# ユーザ権限全削除について

Tags: mysql

**あるユーザに付与されている権限を、内容確認することなく一気に全削除する方法はありますか？**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

パスワードもリセットしていいのであれば、ユーザーを削除して作り直すのがが手っ取り早いと思います。

```
DROP USER name@host;
CREATE USER name@host identified by 'newpassword';
```

Comment: なるほど。そういう方法になるわけですね

Answer (score 1):

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGESをつかう方法もあるかと思います。

たとえばshow grantsの結果がこんな感じだったとして

```
mysql> show grants for 'spiderman'@'localhost';
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for spiderman@localhost                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'spiderman'@'localhost'                  |
| GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON `NewYork`.* TO 'spiderman'@'localhost' |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

以下のコマンドを実行することで与えた権限を失効することができます。

```
mysql> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON `NewYork`.* FROM 'spiderman'@'localhost';
```

実行後

```
mysql> show grants for 'spiderman'@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Grants for spiderman@localhost                |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'spiderman'@'localhost' |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

本家にあった[質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799806/remove-privileges-from-mysql-database)